# How can I use a particular picture as a screensaver in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, screensaver

Yes, I want a static *screensaver*, which would be one of the pics that I have.

I find no such option in the screensaver options list:

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You know, using a truly static screensaver defeats the purpose of a screensaver (which is to prevent screen burn-in from leaving a static image up!) This isn't as much of a problem with LCDs as it is with CRTs or plasma displays, but it's still probably not the best approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this link:

- http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/setup/tips/diyscreensaver.mspx

To set up the location of a folder that contains your pictures (or only one picture, as you want), follow the instructions here:

- http://www.knowzy.com/Computers/Software/Screensavers/How_to_Create_a_My_Pictures_Screensaver_Slideshow-StepByStep-2_Configure_Screensaver.htm

Comment: I have a lot of pictures in there, is there a way to do this without having to empty my pictures folder (and putting just this particular image)?

Comment: See the edit for the location setup.

Comment: You are welcome, glad to help!